# How two or more templates can be rendered in web.py?

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, ubuntu-14.04, web.py

I am trying  to run two templates with web.py but the following code gives the following error.[***500 Internal Server]***

Thank You for your help!

```
import web
import pymongo
import datetime


render =  web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'login'
    '/index', 'index'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

web.config.debug= False



class login:    
    def GET(self):   
        return render.login()

    def POST(self):   
        i=web.input()
        print i

class index:
    def GET(self):   
        return render.index()

        def POST(self):   
        i=web.input()
        print i

if __name__ == "__main__":app.run()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 239, in process
    return self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/application.py", line 419, in _delegate
    cls = fvars[f]
KeyError: u'login/index'

127.0.0.1:44423 - - [24/Mar/2015 11:03:17] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 500 Internal Server Error
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing comma:

```
urls = ( '/', 'login', '/index', 'index' )
#                HERE^
```

FYI, here is what happens without the comma:

```
>>> urls = ( '/', 'login' '/index', 'index' )
>>> urls
('/', 'login/index', 'index')
```